# Force content discovery with Zune PC software?

Tags: zune, windows-phone

I have a PC and a Windows Phone 7. I have downloaded several .mp4 TED talks. I put them in the "My Videos" folder, but Zune isn't adding them to my collection. Thus, I can't figure out how to sync them with my phone.

How can I force them to be added to the collection, or manually sync to the phone? Is it possible that they have been added to the collection, but just aren't visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't that the content wasn't being discovered - I was looking under "Video", and the content was appearing under "Podcasts".